# Strip trailing non-word character(s)

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to strip any non-alphanumeric characters from the end of strings using PHP's preg_replace:

`Word One, Two, -`, `Word One, Two,[space]`, `Word One, Two,`, `Word One, Two` should all become `Word One, Two`.

I have tried `preg_replace('/(.+)\\W+$/', '$1', 'Word One, Two, -');` but this only strips the last non-word character. I also tried `'/(.+)\\W*$/'` as I assumed this would make it work if 0 or 1 non-word characters are found (as I need) but it then doesn't match at all. I think I need to make the `\W` greedy but I'm not sure how. Any ideas? Also, please feel free to explain to me what I am doing wrong so I don't find myself haunting the SO regex tag ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `(.+)` eats up all other character, including non-word characters. The regex engine starts matching the string and starts out with *all* characters in the capturing group. Only then it notices that the `\W` at the end of the string won't fit and backs up, tentatively allowing a single character to be matched by the `\W`. But a single character is all that's needed to satisfy the `\W+`, so it just stops and just strips that single character. That's also the reason why `(.+)\W*$` doesn't work at all, because `\W*` is content with matching nothing at all.

Use

```
preg_replace('/\\W+$/', '', $foo);
```

instead. This avoids the problem by just replacing trailing non-word characters without even trying to match something else.

Another option would be

```
preg_replace('/(.+?)\\W+$/', '$1', $foo);
```

which would use a *lazy* quantifier (`+?`) for the capturing group. This quantifier tries satisfying the match while matching *as little as possible* (as opposed to `+` which tries to match *as much as possible* as we saw above). But generally I'd avoid replacing parts of the match by themselves if you can avoid it. To strip things from a string you certainly don't need to match more than you need to strip.

Comment: http://regular-expression.info is a gret learning resource, by the way. For many things there the inner workings of how the regex engine operates are explained in detail, too.

Answer (score 1):

What your regex is doing is looking for the maximum possible amount of any character, while still keeping at least one non-word at the end.

What you need to do is just drop the `(.+)`, and use:

```
preg_replace("/\W+$/","",$input);
```